# Is there a way to start an archive node of a parachain using snapshots? How can we export/ import relaychain blocks?

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, substrate-archive

Using export-blocks command we can export parachain blocks but when trying to export relay chain blocks we received error field RelaychainSpec not found. Is there a way to take snapshot of a parachain efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are snapshots available for Polkadot and parachains in a few different places. Here are just a few from a google search:

- https://polkashots.io/
- https://p2p.org/snapshot/polkadot
- https://polkachu.com/snapshots

There are many more.

These are generated by simply copying the folder which holds the state of the chain.

On mac for example, the default folder is:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/<chain_name>/chains/<chain_name>
```

You would copy that whole folder from one computer to another computer.

Comment: I am aware of backing up data directory and restarting using that. I was wondering if we can just export blocks using substrate cli for parachain archive node. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: What do you mean though? What is "export blocks" mean which is not provided by the `export-block` command?

Comment: ya so the issue is i can pass parachain spec file to export-block command to backup all the blocks in a range from our archive node  but cant do the same by passing relaychain spec. It gives error `field RelayChainSpec is missing`  when i try to do that. I think it implies relay blocks can only be exported from relay chain archive right? @Shawn Tabrizi